# Mac showing large color circles after waking up

Tags: imac

I'm on a 27-inch iMac from late 2015, using macOS Mojave (version 10.14.6), and yesterday and today, it's randomly happened that these large circles appear on the entire screen when I wake it up from sleep mode after a few hours (or overnight). It stays frozen for a couple of seconds, and then the screen goes back to normal (photo below).

If it's asleep for only a short period of time (like a few minutes), the circles don't show but everything on my screen is slightly orange.

It doesn't happen every time, so I'm not sure taking it into the store would be beneficial? Any ideas? I've tried restarting, running an update, and unplugged it.

[image]

Comment: Take a screenshot.  If the image doesn’t show the circles, it’s hardware. You need to take it in for service.  See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345216/mid-2013-macbook-pro-displaying-multi-color

Comment: @Allan so I tried that today, but the computer is also a bit "frozen" during this time too, so it wouldn't let me do a screenshot.

Comment: Boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting).  See if you can do the screenshot then.  You might also want to [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold `D` while booting) to see if it detects any hardware problems.

Comment: I took it to the Apple store today and they ran a bunch of different tests, and found nothing wrong. Ugh.

Comment: Did it show like your picture in the Apple Store?