# Why does a Macbook pro's internal screen flicker ONLY when it is on a GPU?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, gpu, temperature

I have a Macbook pro 2017 (15 inch, touchbar).

Since a couple of months ago, once the laptop is on GPU for a long time (at least 3-4 hours), the internal screen **starts to flicker**, like this:

[image]

The flickering gets worse until the internal monitor turns into blank screen (even though it is technically ON, the backlight is working, but it shows just a black image). The external monitors have no issues at the same time and show the correct image.

I took the laptop to Apple genius bar and showed a recorded video of the issue. Apple repair team could not reproduce the issue even after a video triage (because it only appears after some hours of use). Despite that, they **REPLACED the Logic Board, the Top Case, the I/O Board, and the battery**, hoping that the issue will never show up again.

Unfortunately, screen flickering re-appeared after receiving it back.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Here are my speculations:

- It's NOT a GPU issue: The GPU is attached to the logic board and is recently replaced, while the problem persists. Besides, when the internal monitor starts to flicker, the  external monitors that use the same GPU (though, via USB-C) do not flicker. It only happens for the internal monitor.
- It's NOT an internal MONITOR issue: Screen flickering appears only after hours of use, when the GPU is enabled (i.e. when the laptop is connected to the external display, OR if I disable the internal Intel graphics card in power settings). Interestingly, when the screen flickers, switching back to the internal intel graphics card resolves the flickering. I just have to detach the external monitors and/or enable automatic graphics switching, and the flickering disappears after a few seconds. Detach the external monitors and the internal monitor starts to flicker again.
- It is related to heat but not all about overheating: The problem only arises after a few hours of use, but I don't think there is an OVERheating issue. When the screen starts to flicker, none of the GPU sensors shows a high temperature. The internal sensor reports a GPU temperature of at most 55°C.

What else could be the cause of the this? It's weird enoguht that half of the laptop is replaced but the issue is still there..

My own hypothesis is that:

- The **LVDS cable** that transfers data from the GPU to the internal monitor is affected by heat or damaged... But I wonder... Isn't it the same cable that transfers data from the "Internal HD Graphics card" to the internal monitor? Why does it only happen when I am using the GPU? Is it easy/cheap to replace this cable?
- Since the GPU is OK for the external monitors (all 1080p) but flickers for the internal monitor (2880-by-1800), then maybe the GPU cannot feed a high-resolution screen when it is warmed up (again, heating issue?)

What could be the cause if this mystery?

P.S. Resetting the SMC and PRAM did not work.

P.S. Apple diagnostics shows no issue.

[image]

Comment: It could be your GPU or the [video mux](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345227/119271);  it could also be a failing chip or some of the related circuitry.  Unless a tech puts hands on with proper diagnostic equipment, it's only a guess.  You need to take this in to be serviced (if you take it to Apple, they'll most likely just recommend replacing the whole logic board)

Comment: @Allan, I did. Apple repairmen have recently replaced the whole logic board (along with the Top Case and the I/O Board). If they could reproduce the issue themselves, then I would have not needed such as brainstorming here ;)

Comment: @Allan, Isn't the Video mux a part of the logic board (which is just replaced?)

Comment: Yes, it is.  Why would they replace the top case (keyboard, trackpad, and battery) as none of that has anything to do with video.  Was this done under warranty?  Also, just so you know, they don't necessarily use new logic boards - many are remans and their quality control is horrid.  Assuming that they replaced it with a working logic board, your only variable left is the display.  Have them replace that and see if it solves the issue.  Did you pay for this repair or was it under AppleCare?

Comment: @Allan, they told me that they realized a swollen battery and weird stuff around the USB ports, hence they replaced all these. The laptop was out of warranty, but since they weren't expecting a 2017 MBP to be in such shape, they did not charge me for the replacements. They were hoping that the flickering issue will go away after all these replacements, but it didn't.

Comment: @Allan , If it's the display, then why it doesn't flicker when the Intel HD Graphics is in use? It appears only when the Radeon card is active. Are the cables separate? If the internal monitor is connected to the two graphic chips via SEPARATE cables, then  would explain the issue.

Comment: As the old saying goes if you have eliminated everything else, whatever remains, however implausible, must be the cause (sorry Sherlock...) So you have to look at the things that were NOT replaced. Could it be the display itself? What else that effects video could be the cause (make a list, and eliminate one at a time) Do you have an external monitor you can test with?

Comment: That's why I think it's the mux.  You're focusing on cables, but there are no cables other than the LVDS cable connecting the internal display to the logic board.  The external monitors are connected via the USB-C port and there's no cable going from the mux to the port - it's all on the PCB. The [cable is actually a ribbon](https://bit.ly/2Bkffk9) and not what's commonly thought of as "a cable."

Comment: A couple things:  1) The [battery doesn't come into contact with anything on the logic board](https://bit.ly/32HtDOL) so battery swelling around the USB ports is impossible. 2) The top case has nothing relevant to the video 3) Out of warranty for free?  Was this Apple or an ASR?  4) for a video issue they ignored the biggest video component of them all - the display.  If your display is good, it's the mux - it has to be.  I'd have them swap the display at this point.  5) A technician replacing parts "hoping" is a red flag - they don't know what they're doing and these parts are expensive!

Comment: @Allan, thanks for the amazing answers. So if it's the mux, then it means the newly replaced logic board should be replaced with yet another one. Doesn't it sound weird to have such an uncommon issue on two different logic boards?

Comment: I was kind of dancing around it...I don't think they changed the logic board.  They're expensive.  When you said that the battery was swelling and affecting the USB, well, that's impossible.  If you had trackpad issues, I could see that, but the battery and the LVDS connector and the USB connector and mux are nowhere near each other. I don't have confidence in these guys and if I can point you in a direction to get quality service, I'm happy to help.

Comment: @Allan, 1) The battery has nothing to do with the USB. They opened it up and saw that the battery and "something around the USB ports" are not OK (for separate reasons), so they replaced them both. 2) No idea why the top case is replaced. 3) It was Apple's own Genius bar, London. They waived it because "they weren't expecting a device of this age to face such issues.". 4) No question 4!

Comment: @Allan, 5) Yep, their repair procedure is weird to me. The only problem then & now is how to make them produce the issue. They don't want to wait for the monitor to warm up for a couple of hours to reproduce the issue, and the flickering disappears if the laptop is cooled down (while opening it up). I understand that it's hard to fix a fault without reproducing it.

Comment: @Allan, it's unlikely that they didn't change the Logic board and other stuff. It's Apple, right? In their work confirmation email, they listed all the parts with their new serial numbers: "661-07793 Logic Board, 2.9GHZ, 16GB, RP560, 512GB, ETSI
Replacement Serial No: ...", "661-07954 Top Case with Battery, ANSI, Space Gray
Replacement Serial No: ...", "923-01480 I/O Board".

Comment: They will probably charge me this time, so I was about to suggest them change the LVDS , which should be "cheap to try". (though not sure why there's no issue when Radeon is off). Making them believe it could be the mux is difficult. 

The fun part is that the genius bar does not take note of what I say, they just send it for video triage and try to figure out the issue themselves and even skip the triage and open it up to see what could be wrong. Does it sound like a good idea to take it to a different branch or shall I work with the same guys who are now (supposedly) into the issue?

Comment: Not a fan of the "geniuses" but that's for another day.  :-}  I would have them replace the display.  Mention "Flex Gate."  That might help.

Comment: @Allan, thanks for the discussion. One last question: the [flex gate issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aihRru-lCns) is resolved by replacing the LVDS, right? Is the LVDS replacement cheap, or am I gonna pay for the entire display? Apparently the 2017 15-inch laptops are not a part of Apple's free [flexgate replacement program](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/13-inch-macbook-pro-display-backlight-service)

Comment: I don't know.  That's why I recommended mentioning flex gate. It's meant to be a reminder to the Apple person that they've had tons of display issues and here you are experiencing a display issue that renders your Mac useless - that they failed to fix the first time.  Trying to take the sympathy angle.

Comment: @Allan, that's a smart approach. Thanks :)))

Comment: @Ali, were you able to resolve this? I have the exact same issue, though I am using Macbook Pro 13 (2017) touch bar.

Comment: @darKnight Nope. Apple suggests replacing the screen (which includes cable) but it costs abour £800 (if I remember correctly), so I'm using the laptop mostly as a workstation and use an external monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I've been diagnosing a similar issue. It's helpful to run this tool with various configurations, then use unix `diff` to compare the configuration settings.

```
/System/Library/Extensions/AppleGraphicsControl.kext/Contents/MacOS/AGDCDiagnose
```

e.g.

```
diff -u AGDCDiagnose-high-freq-after-detection.txt AGDCDiagnose-without-EDR.txt |
@@ -1772,8 +2354,8 @@
 Link Lanes 4 {4,4}
 Link Rate (Mbps)   3240 {3240,3240}
 Link Bits  30 {18,30}
-Voltage Swing (Level)  {255,255,255,255}
-Pre-Emphasis (Level)   {255,255,255,255}
+Voltage Swing (Level)  {0,0,0,0}
+Pre-Emphasis (Level)   {0,0,0,0}
 Spread Enabled
 Enhanced Framing   Enabled
 Scrambler  Enabled
@@ -1820,7 +2402,7 @@
 DIG FE B
 Number of Devices  1
 Timing DICT    21
-Display Mode   80004003
+Display Mode   80006003
 Refresh Rate (Calculated)  60 Hz
 Refresh Rate (Stored)  0.0 Hz
 Window (Active)    2880 x 1800
@@ -1924,7 +2506,7 @@
 DIG FE A
 Number of Devices  1
 Timing DICT    21
-Display Mode   80005022
+Display Mode   80003022
 Refresh Rate (Calculated)  60 Hz
 Refresh Rate (Stored)  0.0 Hz
 Window (Active)    3840 x 2160
@@ -1947,12 +2529,12 @@
 Dynamic Range  1 (SDR)
```